# windows-ce usb touch driver does not get enumerated

Tags: touch, usb, screen, driver, windows-ce

I added usb touch screen driver to my custom win ce 6.0 OS image. The touch screen works only when there is another USB device(USB flash drive, usb mouse etc.) present in the system and does not work when there is only single usb touch screen is connected. After troubleshooting, I discovered that the USB touch device does not get enumerated. Any help resolving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Do you have a specific programming issue?  I can't tell from your brief description if this is a device problem better suited for a different Stack Exchange site, or if you have a problem with a program you are working on.  If it's the latter, please edit your question to include your code that isn't working.

Comment: If you're the OEM, this sounds like a BSP issue that you should raise with your vendor (TI or Qualcomm, probably). If you're not the OEM, then you probably can't do whatever you're trying to do.